Azure Runtime Updated Function does not work in one environment while running properly in other env
I have updated my azure functions from 3.x to 4.x, resolved all the breaking changes per MS Docs, the functions seemed to work fine in our Dev and Qa environments without any issues, but the same when deployed to UAT environment does not work. While viewing the function in the portal, I get the following error :
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more loaded extensions do not meet the minimum requirements. For more information see https://aka.ms/func-min-extension-versions. Extension StartupType CosmosDB IWebJobsStartup from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not meet the required minimum version of 3.0.9.0. Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB to 3.0.9 site
As per the above error, it states one of our nuget package being used is not compatible, but I have confirmed we are using the latest nuget package, the same which is deployed to Dev and Qa environment. So why is it still referring to an old package version.
This causes the function, which is used by the website to load data, to return 503 error with 'Function host is not running' as response. We have also recently introduced staging slots to the UAT environment, but I do not think this is related to that. Any leads will be helpful.
Thank You

Did you try to update the package, see this answer

It's likely that your client or dependent application is not referencing the correct deployment slot.
Get Staging Slot URL or Key:

Navigate to the Azure Portal.
Go to your Azure Function App and select the staging slot.
Under the Configuration or Deployment slots section, you can find the URL and key for the staging slot.

Using Staging Slot URL:
In your dependent application, use the staging slot's URL to make HTTP requests to the Azure Function.

Which URL are you referring to here?

@HarshalBhoir More information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots?tabs=azure-portal#view-slots
